# Array into mysql columns syntax

Tags: php, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional associative array that I run through and grab a specific value that is then echoed out.

```
foreach ($multi_array as $entry) {

   echo $entry['tag_id'];

}
```

It echos `12`. What function could I use to convert it to...

```
`1`,`2`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function, try this:

```
$result = '`' . implode('`,`', $multi_array) . '`';
```